# Spring Integration: channel gets wrong payload

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have this code, but its not working properly. Aggregator gets wrong payload type - Entity instead of List<Message<?>>. Could anyone please explain me? thanks in advance!
Flow pipline:

```
        @Bean
    IntegrationFlow regularStageFlow() {
        return flow -> flow.channel(OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
                .split()
                .publishSubscribeChannel(subscriber -> subscriber
                                .subscribe(s ->
                                           s.filter(source -> filter1((Entity)source))
                                          .handle(this::createCsvPackage)
                                          .channel(FTP_CHANNEL)
                                )
                                .subscribe(s -> s.filter(source -> filter2((Entity)source))
                                                
                         .handle(this::createPdfPackage)
                         .channel(FTP_CHANNEL)
                                )
                                .subscribe(s -> s.filter(source -> filter3((Entity)source))
                                                
                          .handle(this::createAllPackage)
                           .channel(FTP_CHANNEL)
                                )
                )
                ;
    }
```

every handler in handle looks like

```
    private List<Message<?>> createCsvPackage(Entity payload, MessageHeaders headers) {
        return createCommonPackage(payload, headers, flag);
}
```

common handler:

```
List<Message<?>> createCommonPackage(Entity payload, MessageHeaders headers, boolean flag) {
   //do some logic and return List<Message<?>>
}
```

want to have List<Message<?>> in aggregator in payload, but have Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is expected.
Just because you have that `publishSubscribeChannel()` configuration and its nature is that not only those `subscribe()` sub-flows are only subscribers, but also the next endpoint in the flow becomes a subscriber of this channel.

We don't explain that in the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows

But the sample from there really demonstrates expectations.

However we do explain previously in that doc that `IntegrationFlow` is like a chain - the next endpoint is subscribed to the current channel.

If you'd like to stick with a `publishSubscribeChannel` and an `aggregate` combination, then you need to separate them into individual `IntegrationFlow` definitions. Where every subscriber would end with a input channel of the flow with an `aggregate()`.

However what you are looking for is solved on the framework side with respective pattern implementation - `scatterGather()`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#scatter-gather

Comment: what is better approach for achievement this aim? thanks Artem Bilan

Comment: What you show so far with those 3 service calls and collecting their results in one place is indeed the task for Scatter-Gather.

Comment: thanks Artem Bilan. I was a bit wrong. It seems like aggregation is not necessary for me, I want to pass to the output channel List<Message<?>> but instead of List<Message<?>> I have Entity of payload type. scatterGather is not my variant because its for aggregation. I updated description of question

Comment: add channel(FTP_CHANNEL) to all subscribers - and it seems like it works...Am I right or wrong?

Comment: The `List<Message<?>>` you can only after aggregation of results of those subscribers. That `.channel(FTP_CHANNEL)` becomes one more subscriber to that `publishSubscribeChannel` via internal `bridge()` endpoint. That's really not what you are asking for.

Comment: The general rule: if you go `publishSubscribeChannel()` and all of the subscribers has an output channel, then this `publishSubscribeChannel()` must be the last operator in this flow. That's to avoid a confusion of the next endpoint in the flow becoming one more subscriber. I'm going to fix the doc mentioning such a situation.

Comment: I return List<Message<?>> from every handle, for ex: handle(this::createCsvPackage), where List<Message<?>> createCsvPackage(){//to do sm}.

Comment: Return where? If just send to the same channel from all subscribers, then you need to follow my advice: the `publishSubscribeChannel()` is the end for this flow and a new flow for that common channel to start from in the other `IntegrationFlow`.

Comment: updated original question

Comment: Yes. That looks OK. What is the question yet?

Comment: may be not for now, need to think about new knowledge more)) thanks for your help, spring integration is the most complex module for me, want to good understand it very much

Comment: For that purpose start from EIP book: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/. It will give you a conceptual understanding in message, endpoints and channels between them.